# How do I make Recycler view replace existing items instead of adding to it?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I've figured out how to get the sorted data with a query and pass that to the Recycler view, *but it only adds to the RecyclerView instead of replacing the already existing items*. Uploaded the code to Pastebin since code irrelevant to the problem is in the class.

MyDatabaseHelper class = https://pastebin.com/fXHw5ccb

CustomAdapter class = https://pastebin.com/4epLqWzJ

MainActivity class = https://pastebin.com/h5mDQunv

Including

```
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

or removing it doesn't solve the problem.

How it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK8iD.png

How I want it to look after clicking the [menu sort item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJPrI.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSNEL.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: Had to pass Custom Adapter to a custom object and read the ArrayList from the object, which let me sort based on SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you call `storeFoodDataInArrayList()` multiple times which populates the `food_ID` array, but you never clear that array.

Clear the `food_ID` array before populating it.